# Changing the location of the starting node in a Game tree

Tags: tables

I would like to change the location of Player 3 and the node below such that the spreading lines end directly in the middle above player 1, respectively player 2. Does anyone has a quick solution?
Sorry I am new here and I don`t know what to do to compile the following code, but it works in Latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle{solid node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2];
    \tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw, inner sep=1.2];
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1cm,sibling distance=6cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1cm,sibling distance=4cm]
    \node(0)[hollow node]{}
    child{node{}
        edge from parent node[above left]{C}
    }
    child{node{}
        edge from parent node[above right]{D}
    };
    \node[circle, label=above:{Player 3}]at(0){};
    \node[below]at(0-1){
        \arrayrulewidth.75pt
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Player 2}} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        &  & $A$ & $B$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & $A$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $2$ , $2$ , $3$ }   & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $0$ , $4$ , $1$ }  \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \raisebox{1.5ex}[-1.5ex]{\textit{Player 1}} & $B$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $4$ , $0$ , $2$ } & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $1$ , $1$ , $4$ } \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \node[below,xshift=-15]at(0-2){
        \arrayrulewidth.75pt
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Player 2}} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        &  & $A$ & $B$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & $A$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $2$ , $2$ , $3$ }   & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $0$ , $4$ , $1$ }  \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \raisebox{1.5ex}[-1.5ex]{\textit{Player 1}} & $B$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $4$ , $0$ , $2$ } & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $1$ , $1$ , $4$ } \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Why are you loading `forest`? You aren't using it. You might also look at `ist-game`.

Comment: Which player 1 and player 2? You have two identical children. Each has player 2 at the top and player 1 at the left. It is not at all clear where player 3 should move to or where the lines should go.

Comment: Thanks. Depending on player 3`s choice, player 1 and 2 end up in different games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`istgame`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package, you can do it like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\def\gameC{%
        \arrayrulewidth.75pt
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Player 2}} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        &  & $A$ & $B$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & $A$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $2$ , $2$ , $3$ }   
              & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $0$ , $4$ , $1$ }  \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \raisebox{1.5ex}[-1.5ex]{\textit{Player 1}} 
        & $B$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $4$ , $0$ , $2$ } 
              & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $1$ , $1$ , $4$ } \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
}
\def\gameD{%
        \arrayrulewidth.75pt
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Player 2}} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        &  & $A$ & $B$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & $A$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $2$ , $2$ , $3$ }   
              & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $0$ , $4$ , $1$ }  \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \raisebox{1.5ex}[-1.5ex]{\textit{Player 1}} 
        & $B$ & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $4$ , $0$ , $2$ } 
              & \makebox[1.8cm][s]{ $1$ , $1$ , $4$ } \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5]
\xtdistance{10mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0)[initial node]{Player 3}
  \istb{C}[al]{\gameC}[below,xshift=-12mm]
  \istb{D}[ar]{\gameD}[below,xshift=-12mm]
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying with the package{game} but it was not compatible with another package and I didn`t know about package{istgame}.